# ¿Es peligroso usar innerHTML en Javascript? ¿Qué otra alternativa tengo?

Tags: javascript, seguridad

He leído que es peligroso usar `innerHTML` en Javascript, que incluso se pueden sufrir ataques XSS.

En este código por ejemplo, desde el `input` se puede embeber una imagen muy fácilmente si escribimos esto en el `input`:

```
Hola <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/ES/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif">
```

aparece en el `div` la imagen Donar de PayPal.

Según he leído, otros ataques más graves son posibles, incluso ejecutar código en el servidor ¿ ?

Lo que quiero saber es hasta qué punto puede ser peligroso el uso de `innerHTML` y que alternativas más seguras pueden existir.

```js
var theInput = document.getElementById("ibxTest");
var theDiv = document.getElementById("content");

theInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var text = this.value;
  theDiv.innerHTML = text;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ibxTest" />
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Hay una [respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16860343/7291849) que puede q responda la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que el problema es como su ejemplo, cuando muestra lo que entra el usario. El innerHTML no es peligroso per se, el problemo es cual texto utiliza para determinar lo que mete en el innerHTML.  Si utiliza texto entrado por el usario (como en su ejemplo) si, XSS puede ser un gran problema.

Comment: Una alternativa a innerHTML es [innerText] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Comment: Todos los datos aportados por el usuario deben de tratarse como potencialmente peligrosos. Puedes sanitizar el texto justo cuando lo lees, para tranquilidad posterior, o escaparlo cada vez que lo uses. Pero con una vez que se te olvide escaparlo, estarás

Comment: Es peligroso mientras no controles los datos que introduce el usuario... tal y como lo es un $_POST[''] o $_GET[''] en PHP... si tienes un control de validación y sanitización no tiene por que dar problemas.

Answer (score 3):

Prácticamente, se considera riesgo a todo dato introducido por un usuario, es nuestro deber como programador validar y sanitizar los datos para asegurar la integridad de la información y la seguridad del sistema.

El uso de la propiedad `innerHTML` deberá ser bajo un ambiente sumamente controlado y aún así es preferible utilizar otros métodos para la creación y adición de contenido (seguir leyendo).

[Carlos Souza](https://gist.github.com/caike) (@caike) en su gist titulado «[XSS attack demo with innerHTML](https://gist.github.com/caike/35522c3da161d29fc2ce)» nos brinda una clara idea de como es un código diseñado para ataque XSS:

```
// Comentarios traducidos.
// Probado en Chrome, Firefox y Safari.

// El siguiente código no lanzará una alerta.
target.innerHTML = "<script> alert('XSS Attack'); </script>";

// El siguiente código, lanzará una alerta.
target.innerHTML = "<img src=x onerror=\"alert('XSS Attack')\" >";
```

**¿Qué alternativas existen?** La respuesta puede ser amplia, pero buscaré resumirla lo más posible, ya que va en función del objetivo buscado:

- Si se desea mostrar texto dentro de un nodo, se recomienda la propiedad [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent): debido a que dicha propiedad se encarga de validar y sanitizar el contenido en caso de que hubiere código HTML y entre éste una alguna etiqueta `script`.
- Si se buscas tener una alta interacción entre creación/edición de elementos (en el DOM), podría usarse un motor de plantillas como [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) que ya tiene una gran cantidad de herramientas que nos apoyan a dicha operación de forma segura.
- Si estás usando la librería de [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/), podrías utilizar la función [`.html( htmlString )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) como sustituto, ya que se puede ver en [este código](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L415) el filtro que aplican antes de insertarlo al DOM.
- Si se crearán y añadirán elementos al DOM, utilizar las funciones de [creación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) de elementos y [adición](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) (¡lo sé! es más pesado y más código, pero más seguro).
- Si la interacción con el DOM será controlada, se puede usar de forma discreta la propiedad `innerHTML` (dejar esta opción como último recurso).

**Referencias adicionales:**

> ...In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack....
>
> — [DOM Elements: React](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).
>
> ...an attacker might control into innerHTML normally causes an XSS vulnerability. For example, code contained in a  tag...
>
> — [Angular - Security](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example)