# Eventos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom

Referente al tema de eventos en JS, yo creo una pagina con un input de texto y dos párrafos. ¿Cómo podría añadir información a esos dos párrafos a medida que voy escribiendo en el input? Es decir, que me lo vaya actualizando. Además, en un párrafo debe aparecer el mismo texto que en el input, pero en mayúsculas, y en el otro párrafo igual pero en minúsculas.

```js
    function escribirTexto(){
     var añadeTexto=document.getElementById("añade").value;
    }
```

```html
    
    Formulario&nbsp;<input type="text" id="añade" onekeypress="escribirTexto()">
    
    <p id="añade" onekeypress="escribirTexto()"> Este es el nuevo párrafo 1</p>
    <p id="añade" onekeypress="escribirTexto()"> Este es el nuevo párrafo 2</p>
```

Comment: Adicional a las respuestas ya publicadas, te recomiendo la lectura de: [¿Es peligroso usar innerHTML en Javascript? ¿Qué otra alternativa tengo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/222066/729).

Comment: Es bastante interesante! no sabía de la existencia de estos problemas. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes escuchar el evento `onkeyup` para llamar a una función y realizar tu lógica. [revisa los eventos de input](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp)

Nota: debes evitar usar caracteres especiales como la `ñ` o `tildes` para tus variables [revisa este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-%C3%91-en-nombre-de-variables)

```js
var text_mayuscula = document.getElementById("text_mayuscula");
var text_minuscula = document.getElementById("text_minuscula");

function escribirTexto(){
    var textOriginal=document.getElementById("input_text").value;
    text_mayuscula.innerHTML = textOriginal.toUpperCase();
    text_minuscula.innerHTML = textOriginal.toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
Formulario: <input type="text" id="input_text" onkeyup="escribirTexto()">

<h4>Parrafo en mayúscula:</h4>
<p id="text_mayuscula" > Este es el nuevo párrafo 1</p>
<h4>Párrafo en minúscula:</h4>
<p id="text_minuscula" > Este es el nuevo párrafo 2</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

**correcciones:**
 1. los scripts siempre deben ir al final de documento antes del cierre
        del body `</body>` esto es para que cargen de ultimo, si los colocas
        al principio cargaran antes que los elementos y no podra leer los
        mismos porque aun no existen.
 2. no se usan id con palabras con acentos!
 3. en los tags `<p>` no es necesario llamar a tu funcion!
 4. No es recomendable utilizar innerHTML es mejor textContent o
    innerText

**puedes hacerlo asi:**

```js
// creamos la funcion y le pasamos el input
function escribirTexto(e){

  // "e" es el input envido asi mismo como this;
  // el innerText nos escribe en el parrafo y el value nos optiene el valor
  // la funcion toUpperCase() convierte a mayuscula
// la funcion toLowerCase() convierte a minuscula
  document.getElementById("text_mayuscula").innerText = e.value.toUpperCase();
  document.getElementById("text_minuscula").innerText = e.value.toLowerCase();

}
```

```html
Formulario&nbsp;<input type="text" onkeyup="escribirTexto(this)">

<h4>Parrafo en mayúscula:</h4>
<p id="text_mayuscula" > Este es el nuevo párrafo 1</p>
<h4>Párrafo en minúscula:</h4>
<p id="text_minuscula" > Este es el nuevo párrafo 2</p>
```